# How to get all DataTypes including custom created data types in UMBRACO?

Tags: umbraco

I would like to access all Data Types of UMBRACO through C# code including custom created Data Types. I can get all predefined data types from UMBRACO through **ApplicationContext.Services.DataTypeService** but not custom created data types.

Can anyone help me over here??

Thanks in advance.

Harshil Shukla

Answer (score 5):

You can use

```
var allDataTypeDefinitions = ApplicationContext.Services.DataTypeService.GetAllDataTypeDefinitions();
```

This will return you a IEnumerable with all the information of your data types.

More information [here](http://our.umbraco.org/Documentation/Reference/Management-v6/Services/DataTypeService). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
umbraco.cms.businesslogic.datatype.DataTypeDefinition[] dataTypes
  =  umbraco.cms.businesslogic.datatype.DataTypeDefinition.GetAll();
```

Comment: For which version you are talking about this I am using V 6.1.6 and in it there is nothing like businesslogic.